# Lograr efecto slider al seleccionar una opcion

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de lograr un efecto tipo slider que al seleccionar una sede los datos de canchas ,horarios y vestuarios se vayan corriendo como un slider segun la opcion seleccionada.Esto se puede hacer con javascript?Soy bastante nuevo en esto asi que espero que se haya entendio dejo el codigo que tengo hasta ahora junto con una imagen

```html
<!-- Sedes -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">SEDES</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-10">
        <div class="tabbable-panel">
            <div class="tabbable-line">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">
                                Tab 1 </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">
                                Tab 2 </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">
                                Tab 3 </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">
                                Tab 3 </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3">
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Sedes -->
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las sedes son los 4 `tabs`? Quieres que cada `tab` tenga un slider?

Comment: si claro las sedes son los cuatro tabs, lo que quiero es que al seleccionar una sede las canchas ,horarios y vestuarios varien segun esa sede seleccionada es decir cada sede tiene un vestuario,horario y canchas

Comment: Estás usando la versión 4 de Bootstrap?

Comment: Sí asi es uso la version 4 de bootstrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto es lo que te propongo:

Lo primero es organizar un poco tu código, estás usando `<div class="col-2">` para cada elemento `<li>`, con eso estás rompiendo el normal comportamiento de la lista `<ul>`, motivo por el cual no funcionan los [`tabs`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs) como deberían.

Supongo que su uso es para justificar los `tabs`, pero para eso ya existe una clase propia de Bootstrap la cual es [`.nav-fill`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#fill-and-justify).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill">
```

También agregué varios [atributos ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel), que aunque **opcionales**, son indispensables como buena práctica para las [tecnologías de apoyo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) como lectores de pantalla.

```
... role="tab" aria-controls="tab_default_1" aria-selected="true">
... role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="default_1-tab">
```

Lo segundo es asignar dentro de cada `tab` un carrusel único, puedes ver [más información en la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/).

En este punto debemos hacer una pausa, el carrusel está listo y funciona, en el ejemplo más básico trabaja con imágenes, pero tú puedes reemplazar estas imágenes por lo que desees, desde [`cards`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/) hasta [`media objects`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/media-object/).

El código que te muestro puede servirte como punto de partida para lo que desees. Solo debes tener especial cuidado en las secciones y en los [selectores ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>

  <!-- Sedes -->
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold">SEDES</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-10">


      <div class="tabbable-panel">
        <div class="tabbable-line">

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="myTab" role="tablist">

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_default_1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_default_2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_default_3" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_default_4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab_default_4" aria-selected="false">Tab 4</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane show active" id="tab_default_1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab_default_1-tab">
              <!-- Aqui dentro va el carrusel que desees del tab1 -->

              <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Tab1+Canchas" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Tab1+Horarios" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Tab1+Vestuario" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>

              <!-- fin carrusel tab_1 -->
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab_default_2-tab">
              <!-- Aqui dentro va el carrusel que desees del tab2 -->

              <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Tab2+Canchas" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Tab2+Horarios" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=Tab2+Vestuario" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>

              <!-- fin carrusel tab_2 -->
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab_default_3-tab">TRES (Aqui iría el tercer carrusel, creo que ya está claro cómo funcionan)
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab_default_4-tab">CUATRO
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Sedes -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: PD: Leyendo tu pregunta veo que nunca mencionas el término carrousel (es [casi lo mismo](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/13988) que un slider)